# Why is the derivative multiplied by $-1$?

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

I have the step by step answers, but I can't discover where the "$-1$" comes from. A constant $= 0$, so it can't be from the inside function.

$$\begin{align*}P'(t) &= \frac{d}{dt}\left[20\left(1+e^{10-t}\right)^{-1}\right] \\ &= -20\left(1+e^{10-t}\right)^{-2}\cdot \frac{d}{dt}\left[1+e^{10-t}\right] \\ &= -20\left(1+e^{10-t}\right)^{-2}\cdot \color{red}{\boxed{\color{black}{e^{10-t}\cdot (-1)}}} \\ &= 20e^{10-t}\left(1+e^{10-t}\right)^{-2}\end{align*} \\$$

---

Thank you so much for the quick responses.

Comment: Instead of adding more questions to the original one, it is better to create a new question or - if they are closely connected with the given question - to discuss them in the commentary thread of a given answer. That way, given answers stay focussed and do not become  incomplete, which might be confusing for users who see the page later.

Comment: Great point. I'll take your advice, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because $e^{10-t}$ has also to be differentiated using the chain rule:

- $\frac d{dt}(e^{10-t}) = e^{10-t}\cdot \frac d{dt}(10-t) = e^{10-t}\cdot (-1)$

Comment: Why did we not do anything with the 10, as it remained in the exponent, but t was used? thank you

Comment: @Anon : $10$ is a constant and its derivative is $0$. Basically, in the last step, the addition rule for derivatives is used: $\frac d{dt}(10-t) = \frac d{dt}(10) - \frac d{dt}(t) = 0-1 = -1$

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is multiplied by $-1$ because that is the derivative of the exponent, $10-t$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the derivative of an exponential function is given by

$$\frac{d}{dt} e^{f(t)} = e^{f(t)} \cdot \frac{d}{dt}\left(f(t))\right).$$

Here, we can identify $f(t) = 10 - t$, so we obtain

$$\frac{d}{dt} e^{10 - t} = e^{10 - t} \cdot \frac{d}{dt} (10 - t) = -e^{10 - t}. $$

Comment: In the last line shout be $t$ in $d/dt$

Comment: Why did we not do anything with the 10, as it remained in the exponent, but t was used? thank you

Comment: @Anon The derivative of $10$ is a constant. We get $\frac{d}{dt}(10 - t) = \frac{d}{dt} 10 - \frac{d}{dt} t = 0 - 1 = -1$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{d}{dt} e^{10-t}=\frac{d}{dt}(10-t)\times e^{10-t}=(-1)\times e^{10-t}$